# Links in Microsoft Office always open in Edge (instead of default browser)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, links, microsoft-edge

I've encountered an annoying issue where any links in Microsoft Office 2010 applications (Word, Excel, Outlook) installed on Windows 10 *always* open links in Microsoft Edge. This is despite having set Firefox or Chrome (I tested both) as the default browser.

HTML files and links from other applications open in the default browser as expected. MS Office just says *nope* and forces links to open in Edge.

How can I get them to use my selected default browser?

Comment: Fun fact: even in older versions of Windows, Office applications would first use some built-in IE component to request the URL ([Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/838028)), and then tell the default browser to open *the result* of that first request. Weirdness if the server asked for a redirect when one was not logged in using IE, even when logged in using the default browser. But I'm sure that's not related.

Comment: Have a look at this answer to a similar question: https://superuser.com/a/1754228/112463

Answer (score 3):

I thought to have the same issue. However, after having a closer look, it turned out, that Office (V2016 in my case) opened

- https-URLs in Edge and
- http-URLs in the defined default browser.

Solution was as follows:

1. Go to "All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Default Programs"
2. Select the desired browser
3. Click "Choose defaults for this program"
4. Tick HTTPS

It's impertinent that on rolling out major updates Microsoft changes user's defaults.

**Addendum 2023**:
[There is a new option in OUTLOOK](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-stop-outlook-links-being-opened-in-edge/89bf6eec-b9ad-40de-a781-09310f304998) to configure how links are opened by Outlook. 
You'll find the setting in `Outlook Options > Advanced > Link Handling > Open hyperlinks from Outlook in:` . 
You then have he choice between "Edge" and "Standard Browser". Guess what Microsoft chose as the default value ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I did try all external options to default browser as Chrome but that did not work. Hence i changed the outlook advanced settings to enable chrome to redirect links from outlook

File - Options - Advanced - Link Handling - 'Default browser' instead of EDGE